# Django prefetch through table

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model which has a `manyToMany` relation with an additional column:

```py
class Field(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(
        Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_(
            u"Table"), related_name="fields"
    )
    supportedLanguages = models.ManyToManyField(
        Language,
        through='FieldsLanguages',
        ('field', 'language'),
        verbose_name=_(
            u"Supportedlanguage"),
        help_text=_(
            u"The language that the field supports (must be a language supported by the table.")
    )
```

Here is my through table:

```py
class FieldsLanguages(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    defaultValue = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u"Default value"),
        help_text=_(
            u"The default value of this field in this language (Overrides the default value of the field).")
    )
```

I would like to retrieve each defaultValue from the through table and its language in one query.

I thought this would do the job:

```py
table = Table.objects.get(pk=1)
fields = list(table.fields.prefetch_related("supportedLanguages").all().order_by("position"))
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't get me the defaultValue of each relation but only its Language. It could be done in the same query as the query goes already through `FieldsLanguages` to retrieve the Foreign Keys.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't really what I was lookig for but it helped me to build my query:

```py
table = Table.objects.get(pk=1)
fields = table.fields.prefetch_related("fieldslanguages_set", "fieldslanguages_set__language").order_by("position")
for field in fields:
    for fl in field.fieldslanguages_set.all():
        print(fl.defaultValue, fl.language)
```

The problem with [Kevin Christopher Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395796/kevin-christopher-henry)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606999/11573842) is that it will query the database for each field in the for-loop. Here it will send only 4 queries.

Answer (score 1):

The through table is a table like any other, which means you can reference it through the related names of its `ForeignKeys`.

```
table = Table.objects.get(pk=1)
fields = table.fields.prefetch_related("fieldslanguages__language")
                     .order_by("position"))

for field in fields:
    for fl in field.fieldslanguages_set.all():
        print(fl.default, fl.language)
```